# adding Recipient to wp_email() is not working?

Tags: wp-mail

I am literally tearing my hair out on this.  Why won't it send?  I think there is something about `$recipient` from a `$var` value that I'm just not getting. 
The same line items are used to create a post and that works so I don't think it's them. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function ecard_email_send(){
$sitename = get_bloginfo('name');
$siteurl = site_url();
$cardurl = ($siteurl . '/' . $post_title);
$recipient = esc_attr($lineItem['recipient_email']);
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$subject = ($lineItem['sender_name'] . ' has sent you an Ecard from ' . $sitename);
$sitename = get_bloginfo('name');
$siteurl = site_url();
$cardurl = ($siteurl . '/' . $post_title);

$content = array(
'name' => $lineItem['recipient_name'],
'verse' => $lineItem['ecard_message'],
'greeting' => $lineItem['ecard_greeting'],
'closing' => $lineItem['ecard_closing'],
'sender' => $lineItem['sender_name'],
'image' => $ecardbackground[0],
'link' => $cardurl,
'value' => 'View your card online'
) ;
 ob_start();
 include(MY_PLUGIN_PATH . '/templates/ecard_email.php');
                $message = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();


$status = wp_mail( $recipient, $subject, $message, $headers );
exit();
 }
```

This is my template edit - or maybe not doesn't seem to format right:

```
<?php /*email template tester */
echo </pre>
!doctype html
body
div
table role="presentation" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"
tr
td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; padding: 40px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #ffffff;"
`'.$content['verse'].'`
/td
/tr
tr
td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; padding: 40px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #ffffff;"
`'.$content['closing'].'`
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; padding: 40px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #ffffff;">
'.$content['closing'].'
/td>
/tr
/table
/div
/body
/html `';`
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem like You are not using the correct variable name in

```
$status = wp_mail( $ecard_recipient, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

You are getting email of recipient in `$recipient`  and in wp_mail() function you are passing another variable for recipient email. 
So, i think this must be the issue you are getting empty variable.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it, i had been trying to see if i used something besides $recipient would have any affect thinking $recipient is used for woocommerce even though i'm not sending the email through woo.  but nope didn't fix anything...  don't know that i'm getting empty vars - its not throwing any errors in the debug or json